# Generating multiple output records for a key in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I have to perform sql 'group by' kind of(not exactly) operation on a large data set.
One simple similar example i can think of is as below in which desired outputs could be 
1)Group the data on (country,city,gender,mother_tongue)
2)Group the data on (country,city,gender,age_group)
3)Group the data on (country,city,age_group)

```
country   city        gender      age_group    mother_tongue     no_of_times_surveyed
----------------------------------------------------------------

USA       new_york     female       middle       english        5
USA       seattle      male         middle       english        2
USA       new_york     female       middle       english        3
USA       new_york     male         middle       french         3
UK        london       male         senior       german         3  
UK        london       male         junior       german         3 
UK        london       male         senior       german         3
```

With a generic map-reduce job i can specify the fields which will be used for grouping but in this way i have to run this job 3 times in this case.
All 3 cases have duplicate computation.(grouping on country,city is common)

If i want to **output records grouped by (country,city)** then (country,city) would be key in the mapreduce job and output should be like

```
USA       new_york     female       middle       english        8
USA       seattle      male         middle       english        2
USA       new_york     male         middle       french         3
UK        london       male         senior       german         6
UK        london       male         junior       german         3
```

**This output can be further grouped on gender/age_group/mother_tongue**.In this mapreduce output there are multiple records for the reducer key (USA,new_york) and (UK,london)

Is it ok to call context.write() more than once in reduce method? Although to do this i would need to store combination of other fields in memory, which could be used for further grouping(gender,age_group and mother_tounge in above example).

Is it possible using multipleOutputs and something I am not aware of?
or Is there no way to achieve this in mapreduce?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. MapReduce is perhaps better named as FlatMapReduce (in functional programming terms). Each call to context.write() generates a new record.

Having said that, your best bet for such highly structured data (or even semi-structured and sometimes even unstructured data), is to use something like Hive. All the of the Relational Algebraic operators have already been implemented by the Hive team. In addition, they've also implemented dozens of SQL Plan optimizations (like the one you described) already.